# Laravel redirect failed login: Method loginUsername does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel `5.6`, and tried to override the `sendFailedLoginResponse` method in `LoginController`, but i get the following error upon bad credentials:

> Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::loginUsername does
>   not exist.

I have two login forms on my website (on `/home` and `/login`). I want to redirect all **failed** attempts to `/login`. This is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect('login')
            ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a function called `loginUsername` anywhere? Cause you're referencing it with `$this->loginUsername()`...

Comment: You have to declare the function `loginUsername`, since you called it in your `sendFailedLoginResponse` function

Answer (score 1):

On the following line you're calling the `loginUsername()` method.

```
->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
```

But as your error declares, the `loginUsername()` method does not exist.
You therefore should declare your `loginUsername()` method, which for example can be this:

```
public function loginUsername() 
{
    return 'email';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out that I used an old function implementation as `sendFailedLoginResponse` as base from a previous Laravel version.

From Laravel `5.3` the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait does not implement the `loginUsername` nor the `getFailedLoginMessage` functions.

Based on the `5.6` code, the following appears to be the best solution:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ])->redirectTo('/login');
}
```